# How to load multiple char values in armv7 assembly program?

Tags: arm, armv7, armv8

I am loading multiple char values in armv7 program using vldm instruction,
but all four values is loading one s register, but I need to expand this values in floating point register (q0).

Please help me. This is my **C** code:

```
 void sum(){ 
 int sum =0;
 char *p =NULL;
 p=( char *) malloc(sizeof( char ) *10); 
 for( int i=0; i<16;++i){
   p[i]=i; sum +=i;
 } 
 printf("sum =%d\n",sum);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical text book example for loading/storing multiple values from/to the vector banks to general purpose registers that may hold destination and source addresses.

```
VLDM r1!, {d0-d7} 
VSTM r0!, {d0-d7}
```

If you are using gdb you may get a better visual of a particular set of banks or groups of registers.

```
(gdb) p $q0
 {u8 = {0 <repeats 16 times>}, u16 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, u32 = {0, 0, 0, 0}, u64 = {0, 0}, f32 = {0, 0, 0, 0}, f64 = {0, 0}}
```